# Fill the unoccupied space near dock

Tags: macos, dock

My dock has 6-7 application icons, so there is space left to the right and left of the dock.

How do I use this space?

Any application gets snapped to the top of the dock, but I would like applications to use the space to the left and right of the dock, and keep the dock visible at all times.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If no one has an answer in a couple days, consider making a screen grab showing your dock area and mark up what you want to see using the markup tools…

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts and suggestions:

1. For a window which is narrower than the empty space at the side of the dock, the window does not get snapped to the top of the dock, rather it glides down to the bottom of the screen. An app with a small window works for this.
2. For a window which overlaps the dock, the snapping is only a gentle snap, you can push the windows further down very easily. It will, of course, be partially hidden by the dock.
3. Make the dock smaller - as small as you can still recognise the icons. Optionally, turn on magnification. For me the choice is between a) mid to large icons with autohide, or b) small icons without autohide but with magnification. For years I used mid-size icons with autohide - I can understand that you don't like autohide, so use small or tiny icons with magnification.
4. Try putting the dock on the side of the screen. I now do this - smallish icons, magnification, and no autohide.
   [image]

Comment: Dock on the side impinges less screen real estate than Dock on the bottom. It's been my placement choice for years.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize windows to extend below the Dock.

But no, the content of application windows will not flow around the Dock …